# Verify whether the key exists in a map and access the iterator in the caller

Tags: c++

I am trying to know in the caller whether the value in the underlying map exists, and if so, return a reference/iterator to it since the caller needs its access.

Typically you check whether the element exists in a map by verifying whether the returned iterator == `map.end()`, but here there's no way in the caller to tell that

```
class A
{
    std::unordered_map<int,int> m = { {5,100} };

    public:
    std::unordered_map<int,int>::iterator get(int key)
    {
        std::unordered_map<int,int>::iterator it = m.find(key);
        return it;
    }  
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    
    auto keyIter = a.get(5);
    // if keyIter is not m.end() ...
    // if keyIter is in m ...
}
```

Comment: You do the check inside `get` and then return the iterator?

Comment: Why not just expose `m.end()` through `A`? Then you'd be able to get your forward iterator and express its end state for the caller.

Comment: I wouldn't want to expose `m` outside of the class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why return an iterator at all? Surely the right way would be to return the int if it exists? If so you can use `optional` to indicate if it is valid or not:

```
std::optional<int> get(int key) {
    std::unordered_map<int,int>::iterator it = m.find(key);
    if (it != m.end())
        return it->second;
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

Usage would then be nice and clean:

```
auto value = a.get(5);
if (value) {
    use_value(*value);
} else {
   std::cout << "Key 5 is not in the map\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks. I like optional's usage here. Any way to generalize the return type rather than hardcoding it too?

Comment: Consider using an if-init expression to limit the scope of the usable value: `if(const auto value = a.get(5); value.has_value()) { use_value(*value); } else { /* No value */ }`

Comment: @xyf You can do `auto get(int key){ auto it = m.find(key); return it != m.end() ? std::make_optional(*it) : std::nullopt; }`